# Java - Ayuda creando un objeto de mi tipo partiendo de otras clases

Tags: java

soy nueva en SO. Necesito una ayuda o un tip con este problema que tengo. No necesito una solucion completa, ni codigo. Si no solo una ayuda a como pensarlo o empezar.

Tengo 3 clases predefinidas:

- GraphDescriptor
- NodeDescriptor
- LinkDescriptor

**GraphDescriptor:**

```
public class GraphDescriptor {
    public Set<NodeDescriptor> nodes;

    public GraphDescriptor() {
        nodes = new HashSet<NodeDescriptor>();
    }

    public Set<NodeDescriptor> getNodes() {
        return nodes;
    }

    public void setNodes(Set<NodeDescriptor> nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }
}
```

**NodeDescriptor:**

```
public class NodeDescriptor {
    private Set<LinkDescriptor> links;

    public NodeDescriptor() {
        links = new HashSet<LinkDescriptor>();
    }

    public Set<LinkDescriptor> getLinks() {
        return links;
    }

    public void setLinks(Set<LinkDescriptor> links) {
        this.links = links;
    }
}
```

**LinkDescriptor:**

```
public class LinkDescriptor {
    private NodeDescriptor sourceNode; //a Descriptor for the source node of the link
    private NodeDescriptor destinationNode; // a Descriptor for the destination node of the link

    public LinkDescriptor() {
    }

    public NodeDescriptor getSourceNode() {
        return sourceNode;
    }

    public void setSourceNode(NodeDescriptor sourceNode) {
        this.sourceNode = sourceNode;
    }

    public NodeDescriptor getDestinationNode() {
        return destinationNode;
    }

    public void setDestinationNode(NodeDescriptor destinationNode) {
        this.destinationNode = destinationNode;
    }

}
```

Por otro lado tengo MIS clases: myGraph, Nodes, Links, Node and Link :

**myGraph:**

```
        public class MyGraph {

            protected Nodes nodes;
            protected Links links;
            protected String name;

            public Nodes getNodes() {
                return nodes;
            }

            public void setNodes(Nodes value) {
                this.nodes = value;
            }

            public Links getLinks() {
                return links;
            }

           public void setLinks(Links value) {
                this.links = value;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String value) {
                this.name = value;
           }
    }
```

**Nodes:**

```
    public class Nodes {

        protected List<Nodes.Node> node;

        public List<Nodes.Node> getNode() {
            if (node == null) {
                node = new ArrayList<Nodes.Node>();
            }
            return this.node;
        }
```

**Node:**

```
        public static class Node {

            protected String name;

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String value) {
                this.name = value;
            }
    }
```

**Links:**

```
        public class Links {

            protected List<Links.Link> link;

            public List<Links.Link> getLink() {
                if (link == null) {
                    link = new ArrayList<Links.Link>();
                }
                return this.link;
            }
    }
```

**Link**

```
public static class Link {

        protected String name;
        protected String source;
        protected String destination;


        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String value) {
            this.name = value;
        }
        public String getSource() {
            return source;
        }

        public void setSource(String value) {
            this.source = value;
        }

        public String getDestination() {
            return destination;
        }

        public void setDestination(String value) {
            this.destination = value;
        }
}
```

Lo que necesito es CREAR *UN OBJETO DE MI TIPO (MyGraph)* dado un objeto *GraphDescriptor*.

El problema es que los objetos descriptores (Node o Link) no tienen un nombre o identificacion y no encuentro una forma de interconectarlos.

Primero, puedo empezar creando un objeto de MyGraph, luego puedo crear un nuevo Nodo por cada NodeDescriptor perteneciente al conjunto de NodeDescriptors del GraphDescriptor.

Despues, por cada NodeDescriptor puedo recorrer su conjunto de LinkDescriptors, setear este nodo como source y crear un nuevo nodo como destination. Y seguir asi hasta el ultimo nodo.

Pero al final voy a tener estos nodos cada uno conectado con links con sus nuevos nodos pero entre estos no habra conexion. Es decir, no tendre un sistema completo, sino varios mini sistemas no conectados. Ese es el problema,no se como unir o conectarlos.

Espero que la duda haya quedado clara y cualquier cosa me pueden preguntar. Gracias!!

(He traducido la pregunta, ya que estaba en ingles y este es SOes.)

Comment: Esto parece un ejercicio... ¿es así? Lo pregunto para saber si tienes que usar esas clases (me da la impresión de que te las han dado) o podrías modelar desde cero tu objeto

Comment: Hola Pablo, GraphDescriptor, NodeDescriptor y LinkDescriptor son dadas, no se pueden cambiar.

Comment: Y ¿cuál es realmente el propósito?, porque quizá no necesitas la clase MyGraph y entonces la pregunta no está del todo clara

Comment: El proposito es crear y llenar un objeto MyGraph con la informacion dada por GraphDescriptor. GraphDescriptor es simplemente un set de NodeDescriptors. Un NodeDescriptor es un set de LinkDescriptors. Un LinkDescriptor tiene un NodeDescriptor como source y un NodeDescripor como destination. El problema es que ninguno de los descriptors tiene un nombre, por lo tanto no se como identificarlos y posteriormente conectarlos. Al final me tiene que quedar un objeto MyGraph, por ejemplo con 10 nodos, estos tienen que estar conectados a traves de Links (con source y destination de entre los 10 nodos).

Comment: Entiendo que quieres representar un grafo dado (mediante un GraphDescriptor) de algún modo especial. Puesto que el objeto original GraphDescriptor ya lo hace, lo que necesitamos saber es qué tipo de representación buscas: ¿mostrar en pantalla el grafo?, ¿Dar nombres a los nodos e indicar la dirección de los enlaces?

Comment: La estructura de clases inicial no tiene datos, son solo referencias de objetos entre si. Para identificarlos podrias usar su representacion toString() que por defecto para cualquier objeto es el nombre de la clase seguido de una representacion hexadecimal del identificador en memoria del objeto, con lo cual tendrias unicidad.